# Git mergetool vimdiff diff3 view changed showing only “LOCAL” files

Tags: bash, vim, git, arch-linux

When solving a merge conflict using `Git` and `Vim` as mergetool, I (suddenly) get a totally different view than I expected and am used to. In the past, I followed [this blog post](https://www.rosipov.com/blog/use-vimdiff-as-git-mergetool/), where the result is a view with four windows: `LOCAL | BASE | REMOTE` and then the file below. Now, I get four windows as well, but `LOCAL` and then `LOCAL | LOCAL | file`.

*I was not able to figure out if the problem lies within `Git` or `Vim`.* I removed my global `.gitconfig` as well as the `.vimrc` but neither helped. What finally helped was to disguise the `HOME` directory for `Git` via this command:

```shell
$ git merge octodog
$ HOME=  git mergetool
```

I assume this behavior is related to a new software version of one or both tools because I had not experienced this in he past. The problem is also independent of directory as well as host, it occurs on a different machine as well.

The versions:

```shell
$ git --version
git version 2.37.1
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0
```

Minimal working example (compressed from the blog post):

```shell
$ cd $(mktemp -d)
$ git init
$ # ––– config mergetool
$ git config merge.tool vimdiff
$ git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
$ git config mergetool.prompt false
$ # ––– create merge conflict
$ echo -e 'cat\ndog\noctopus\noctocat' > animals.txt
$ git add animals.txt
$ git commit -am 'Initial commit'
$ git checkout -b octodog
$ sed -i 's/octopus/octodog/' animals.txt
$ git commit -am "Replace octopus with an octodog"
$ git checkout master
$ sed -i 's/octopus/octoman/' animals.txt
$ git commit -am "Replace octopus with an octoman"
$ # ––– trigger behavior
$ git merge octodog
$ git mergetool
```

What can I do to have the correct diff view again?

Comment: What was the previous version of both tools?

Comment: @romainl vim-8.2.5046-2 and git-2.37.0. You know what? I'll try to downgrade both and maybe figure out which one it was.

Comment: @romainl thank you. I figured it out – it works with `git version 2.36.1` like I'm used to, they seemed to have changed something. Not sure how to proceed further, maybe I'll ask the `Git` developers…

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug git 2.37 (see here: https://lore.kernel.org/git/YshkFWZfBMbuN%2FtI@zacax395.localdomain/t/#r8aa35632787d0df77458137267135c7a6c0d683d).
There was a reimplementation of the way vimdiff is called, cf. the changelog:

```
 * "vimdiff[123]" mergetool drivers have been reimplemented with a
   more generic layout mechanism.
```

This reimplementation does not seem to take the `splitbelow` and `splitright` options into account.

As a workaround you can either downgrade to git version `2.36` (as proposed in the comments by @romainl) or disable the `splitbelow` and `splitright` options until a fix is released.
It seems like the issue (and a potential fix) is already known to the author of the mergetool driver, so it will hopefully be resolved soon.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Ingo's answer said, this is a bug in Git 2.37; it is fixed in Git 2.38, so upgrading to that version will solve the issue too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1157131)